# Nodejs google oAuth2 invalid credentials

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-calendar-api

I have the following piece of code that allows a user to create google calendar events. Initially it will check if the user has an access token set, if not it will initiate the regular oAuth2 authorisation process and get + save the access token and refresh token inside the user profile. The subsequent request will then allow the user to create calendar events via the access token set in his profile.

Here is the code:

```
function getNewToken() {
    const authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES
    });
    return authUrl;
}

module.exports = {
    insert(req, res, next) {
        User.findById(req.user._id, (err, user) => {
            if (user.accessToken) {
                oauth2Client.setCredentials({
                    refresh_token: user.refreshToken
                });
                const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
                calendar.events.quickAdd({ auth: oauth2Client, calendarId: 'primary', text: 'Test Calendar' }, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        next(err);
                    }
                    res.status(200).send('Successfully added calendar event');
                });
            } else {
                const authUrl = getNewToken();
                res.redirect(authUrl);
            }
        });
    },

    googleOauth2Callback(req, res, next) {
        const code = req.query.code;
        oauth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            }
            User.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.user._id }, { accessToken: token.access_token, refreshToken: token.refresh_token }, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    next(err);
                }
            });
            res.send({ token });
        });
    }
};
```

However, I've noticed that after a certain time passes, I get an "401 Invalid Credentials" error. I've noticed that if I omit the access_token and just set the refresh token in the oAuth2Client then everything works as expected.

Is this the right way to handle oAuth2 tokens? Can I just continue using only the refresh token in my API requests? What happens when the refresh token expires? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Is this the right way to handle oAuth2 tokens?**

From what I understand, yes. the tokens are short-lived and will be replaced with a new one once access has been made.

> Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens.

**Can I just continue using only the refresh token in my API requests?**

You can continue to use the tokens if its part of the scope.

> Access tokens are valid only for the set of operations and resources described in the scope of the token request. For example, if an access token is issued for the Google+ API, it does not grant access to the Google Contacts API. You can, however, send that access token to the Google+ API multiple times for similar operations.

**What happens when the refresh token expires?**

Once the access tokens expire, the application uses refresh token to obtain a new one.

In general, this diagram from the Identity documentation illustrates the process fully.

[image]

For more information about oAuth2 in client-side application, check out [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) section of the documentation.

Comment: When I set the credentials usinh the access token and refresh token I get a 401 Invalid Credentials error. However, if I only use the refresh token then everything works fine. From previous examples I've seen, the credentials are always set with both tokens. That's why I was wondering if my process was correct or not.

Comment: I think the process is correct. Basing on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2), Refresh Token will be the one to obtain the Access Tokens. I think that's how to 2 tokens work with each other.